# How do I implement a keyup function with a dynamically create input element with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can not figure out why the following code does not work.
[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/JpwpM/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    addInput();
});

var limit = 30;
function addInput() {
    var numberOfRows = $("#shipping tr").size();
    var id = numberOfRows;
    if (numberOfRows == limit) {
        alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + limit + " inputs");
    } else {
        $('#shipping').append('<tr id="rate' + id + '"></tr>');
        $('tr#rate' + id).append('<td></td>');
        $('tr#rate' + id).append('<td><input type="text" name="rate" /></td>');
    }
    $('input[name=rate]').on('keyup', 'input', function () {
        alert('YAY');
        return false;
    });
}
```

I am trying to assign a keyup function to the inputs that I add dynamically.

Expected output: YAY! inside a popup box

Please help!

Comment: see the demo in answer..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attach an keyup event handler to shipping table, and the event will bubble up from the `input[name="rate"]` to shipping table:

```
$('#shipping').on('keyup', 'input[name="rate"]', function () {
    alert('YAY');
    return false;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/JpwpM/6/)**

Answer (score 3):

You need to add delegation to `document` because its added to the `document`.

**Example**

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input[name="rate"]', function () {
    alert('YAY ');
});
```

#### **[`Working Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/JpwpM/3/)**

Comment: It doesn't make sense to go up all the way to `document` when the `input[name="rate"]` elements are added to the `[id="shipping"]` element